# How does Spring Security hasRole with PreAuthorize works under the hood?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, session, spring-security

I am building a rest API and set `sessionCreationPolicy` of `HttpSecurity` object as STATELESS in my `SecurityFilterChain` method.

Since I could not find how does `hasRole()` method works internally, I wanted to try to see database access per requests which needs authorization.

After modifying database config. file, I can test and see manual queries logged but still can not get a query log from my application "check if this user has that role etc.".

Here is overwritten `doFilterInternal()` method of `AuthTokenFilter` class, which we extend from `OncePerRequestFilter`.

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String jwt = parseJwt(request);
        if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
            String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Is it possible something similar to session storage is used by spring security for authorization purpose, which seems impossible from the way we build `HttpSecurity`.

Comment: what is the reason for doing bad practice and building a custom security solution, when spring security has support for what you have written and had support for it since 2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does `hasRole()` method works internally

If that's the whole point of the question

The first thing to point out is that `hasRole()` is a part authorization mechanism (reminder: authorization is about what access permissions a specific user has). Authorization relies on the authentication, i.e. establishing the identity of the user. To put it simple, what you can do depends on who you're.

So firstly, Filter responsible for authenticating the user creates an instance of `Athentication` and populates it with information including granted authorizes (in the form either *roles* or *authorities*) from the data storage (Database, LDAP data store, and we have an option for testing purposes to store users in memory). Suppose that authentication succeeds, a *fully authenticated* `Athentication` (which returns `true` for `isAthernticated()` call) gets placed into the `SecurityContext`.

Then we can check if the user can access the target resource based on the security roles and information contained in the `Athentication` instance associated with this request.

If you wonder how `hasRole()` is implemented, [*here is the source code*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.java#LC103):

```
public final boolean hasRole(String role) {
    return hasAnyRole(role);
}

@Override
public final boolean hasAnyRole(String... roles) {
    return hasAnyAuthorityName(this.defaultRolePrefix, roles);
}

private boolean hasAnyAuthorityName(String prefix, String... roles) {
    Set<String> roleSet = getAuthoritySet();
    for (String role : roles) {
        String defaultedRole = getRoleWithDefaultPrefix(prefix, role);
        if (roleSet.contains(defaultedRole)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Internally it delegates to `hasAnyRole()` which in turn calls `hasAnyAuthorityName()` (in order to use the same logic for *roles* or *authorities*). Which would prefix the given string with `"ROLE_"` (which a default prefix for roles) and check if the prefixed string is present in the set of authorities extracted from the `Athentication`.

So if you're storing your users in the database, authorities are being pull out from the DB at the stage of Authentication, not during Authorization, when `hasRole()` gets executed.

Comment: Should I understand that Spring Security holds `Authentication` instance associated with this request and per request inside the memory? Can you point me to some official explanation of this storage topic? I was wondering what is the scalability on this approach?

Comment: @yokus Yes, you've understood correctly `Authentication` instance lives and can be accessed at any stage of request processing either via injection in the Beans (for instance Controllers and Services), or through `SecurityContext` from classes not registered in the Spring's Container. After request processing is finished, `SecurityContext` is being cleaned out (you don't need to vary about managing`Authentication` yourself, its live-cycle is controlled by the framework).

Comment: @yokus The main thing you need to remember about `Authentication` that it's a set of credential representing an authenticated user (or an entity that attempts to authenticate when we are looking at what's happening in the authentication filter). And authentication is happening before authorization rules are being applied to the current request.

Comment: @yokus Here's a [link to the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/index.html#servlet-authentication). It feels like you have many questions, a short advice: try to build in your head a general picture of what happening during request processing.

Comment: Many thanks for your time, pointers, and suggestion. It is very useful.